# How do I Install Cake.CoreCLR NuGet package to my tools folder?

Tags: .net-core, cakebuild

Step 1 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41584604/69527) says `Install Cake.CoreCLR NuGet package to your tools folder`. How do I do that?

Things I've tried:

```
> dotnet add package Cake.CoreCLR --version 0.38.4
Could not find any project in `current folder`.
Usage: dotnet add <PROJECT> package [options] <PACKAGE_NAME>
```

and

```
> dotnet tool install Cake.CoreCLR --version 0.38.4 -g
error NU1212: Invalid project-package combination for Cake.CoreCLR 0.38.4. DotnetToolReference project style can only contain references of the DotnetTool type
The tool package could not be restored.
Tool 'cake.coreclr' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:

* You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
* A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET Core tool.
* The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
* You mistyped the name of the tool.

For more reasons, including package naming enforcement, visit https://aka.ms/failure-installing-tool
```

Comment: [Cake.CoreCLR](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cake.CoreCLR/) page on nuget.org shows all available ways to install the package. Did you try to copy/paste package name to google and check the first result? Or even reach the linked answer via comments

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski that's where I got the first thing I tried. There is no information on that page for how to install it in the tools folder.

Answer (score 3):

For running Cake on .NET Core we suggest using the .NET Core tool, installed as a local tool manifest:

```
dotnet new tool-manifest
dotnet tool install Cake.Tool --version 0.38.4
```

Afterwards you need to restore the tool:

```
dotnet tool restore
```

And can run it using `dotnet`:

```
dotnet cake
```

See [Bootstrapping for .NET Core Tool](https://cakebuild.net/docs/getting-started/bootstrapping-scripts#bootstrapping-for.net-core-tool) for details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Cake extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cake-build.cake-vscode) v1.0+, you can install `Cake.CoreCLR` by running a command:

- CTRL + Shift + P (or Command + Shift + P on Mac OSX)
- Choose `Cake: Install debug dependencies`
- And then choose `Cake runner for .NET Core`

This will install `Cake.CoreCLR` to your Cake tools folder.

[image: Cake: Install debug dependencies]

[image: Cake runner for .NET Core]