# Debug Cake Frosting project in VSCode

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, cakebuild

I found an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41583636/how-to-debug-cake-project-in-vscode) related to debugging a cake script in vscode.

*How do I debug a "frosting" project?*

I added this to `.vscode/launch.json`, but it runs the project without stopping at breakpoints:

```json
{
  "name":        "cake",
  "type":        "coreclr",
  "request":     "launch",
  "cwd":         "${workspaceFolder}/build",
  "program":     "dotnet",
  "args":        [ "run" ],
  "stopAtEntry": false
}
```

Comment: Frosting is just an .NET Console application so you would debug it as any .NET application https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/debugging-with-visual-studio-code?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Comment: @devlead Thanks. I found a solution and added it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One must run the frosting console programme (`Build.dll`).

`.vscode/tasks.json`:

```json
{
  "label": "build-cake",
  "command": "dotnet",
  "type": "process",
  "args": [
    "build",
    "${workspaceFolder}/build/Build.csproj",
    "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
    "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
  ],
  "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
},
```

`.vscode/launch.json`

```json
{
  "name": "cake",
  "type": "coreclr",
  "request": "launch",
  "preLaunchTask": "build-cake",
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/build",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/bin/Debug/net6.0/Build.dll",
  "args": [],
  "console": "internalConsole",
  "stopAtEntry": false
}
```